# C# SOAP xml serialization not producing a complete file

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, soap

I'm trying to serialize a few classes in order to create xml based documents to be used with my application.

Im having an issue where the SOAP formatter does not seem to complete its serialization, it does not even completely close its SOAP-ENV.

```
Query obj = new Query();
obj.PrimaryTable = "TEST";
obj.addField(new Field("test", "testField", SQLDataType.VARCHAR));

SoapFormatter formatter;
FileStream fileStream = null;
try
{
    fileStream = new FileStream("C:\\Users\\Lex Southin-Webb\\temp\\Test.xml",
        FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);
    formatter = new SoapFormatter();
    formatter.Serialize(fileStream, obj);
}
catch (Exception exception)
{
    throw exception;
}
finally
{
    if (fileStream != null) fileStream.Close();
    Console.WriteLine("CosedFile");
}
```

The output of the serialization is as follows:

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:clr="http://schemas.microsoft.com/soap/encoding/clr/1.0" SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"
```

As you can see something is going very wrong here. Any ideas as to what? I've tried looking around but have not found a similar issue.

Comment: Is the Query class marked Serializable?

Comment: Yes, it and all of its child classes are marked as serializeable. I'm assuming all base data types are serializable, including Lists and things like that?

Comment: Try to use `Dispose` instead of `Close`. Or add `Flush` after Serialize method.

Comment: calling closse on the filestream does call dispose [filestream.close](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.close.aspx)

Comment: Yeah this did not work also